# How to configure mod_rewrite to serve minified files, if available?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, minify

Here is the problem: we have lots of Javascripts and lots of CSS files, which we'd rather be serving minified. Minification is easy: set up the YUI Compressor, run an Ant task, and it spits out minified files, which we save beside the originals.

So we end up with the following directory structure somewhere inside our DocumentRoot:

```
/
   /js
      /min
         foo-min.js
         bar-min.js
      foo.js
      bar.js
      quux.js
   /css
      ...
```

Now what we need is that Apache serve files from the **min** subdirectory, *and fallback to  serving uncompressed files*, if their minified versions are not available. The last issue is the one I cannot solve.

For example: suppose we have a request to **example.com/js/foo.js** — in this case Apache should send contents of **/js/min/foo-min.js**. There is no minified **quux.js**, so request to **/js/quux.js** returns **/js/quux.js** itself, not 404. Finally, if there is no **/js/fred.js**, it should end up with 404.

Actually, I'm setting build scripts in such a way that unminified files are not deployed on the production server, but this configuration still might be useful on an integration server and on development machines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the configuration that finally worked:

/js/.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /js

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/js/((.+)\.js)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/js/min/%2-min.js -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ min/%2-min.js [L]
```

Same for **css** directory.

Answer (score 3):

You can use RewriteCond to detect the presence of a minified file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUESTURI} ^/js/(.*\.js)
RewriteCond js/min/%1 -f
RewriteRule %1 min/%1 [L]
```

Comment: Doesn't RewriteCond ... -f work with fully qualified filenames? It never worked for me with relative filenames.

Comment: Then change that RewriteCond line to "RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/js/min/%1 -f".

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to change your build scripts? If so, you can configure them to minify the files and give them the same file name, but only when provided the proper flag, e.g. `ant productionDeploy` instead of `ant integrationDeploy`. That way the minification process is completely transparent to everything except the build script.

Comment: Yes, it is possible, and I am implementing the script right this way. But having two versions (original and minified) could be really useful in testing integration config to see if minified versions are not broken in any way.